Unreal Engine 2d upgrade?
I have been trying to code a top down 2d game on Unreal Engine however while there are Youtube tutorials the one i was following just stopped on Unreal 5.1 and then started a new series in 5.3, is it possible to change it from 5.1 to 5.3?
I don't really know what to try because I am new to Unreal and don't want to kill what I have.

Backup the project and open it in the newer version. The old backup will still work with UE5.1.

Upgrading the project to Unreal Engine 5.3 from 5.1 is straightforward. Simply regenerate your project using the new engine version by right clicking your .uproject file and clicking Switch Unreal Engine version... from the menu. Everything should work, especially considering this is a minor version upgrade.


Warning: any Blueprints saved in the upgraded version may not open in a previous Unreal Engine version. This is the Engine's way of protecting your binary assets from corruption. Make sure you have a backup!
